# Locking map of maps for concurrent access

Tags: go

I have a map of maps: map[string]map[string]*Struct which I need to read/write in multiple Go routines.

What is the best way to achieve this ? a Mutex or RWMutex ? and where to place it ?

if I use RWMutex, then should I Lock or RLock before doing an operation which involves both READ & WRITE ?

I tried to have an rwmutex in the root map, but i'm not sure if this is the best way for this issue.

Also I tried to "Lock" before read&write but I receive "concurrent write" panic sometimes.

Comment: Hello, can you use nested [`sync.Map`s](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#Map) instead of `map`? Or does your program require to keep the `map[string]map[string]*Struct`? Because `sync.Map` is pretty convenient to use and not bother about locking at all. If you can't change, no problem, it should still be possible, but I guess the solution would be more "complex".

Comment: @norbjd, I did not try sync.Maps, I will give it a try and report back. 

 I need to have multiple maps under a main map, like map of settings for different "apps", the problem is that having a mutex on the "main map" will lock the whole map for all apps, I'm not sure what is the best way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use RWLock. If the operation involves Write (nevermind with Read or just Write) you need to use Lock, if only Read then RLock/RUnlock.

[Lock](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#Mutex.Lock) can be also considered as exlusive lock. On the other hand, [RLock](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#RWMutex.RLock) is non-exlusive.
RLock can be acquired even if the RWMutex is already locked for reading, but blocks goroutine execution if the resource exclusively locked by Lock method:

```
a blocked Lock call excludes new readers from acquiring the lock
```

On the other hand, Lock method blocks goroutine execution until all readers and writers unlock resource (with RUnlock/Unlock methods). Lock is exclusive because one and only one goroutine can access resource (no matter for reading or writing) until Unlock method called.

Typical approach:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type SomeStruct struct {
    someInfo string
}

type ConcurrentStruct struct {
    mu   sync.RWMutex
    data map[string]map[string]*SomeStruct
}

func New() *ConcurrentStruct {
    return &ConcurrentStruct{
        data: make(map[string]map[string]*SomeStruct),
    }
}

func (cs *ConcurrentStruct) Set(key1, key2 string, val SomeStruct) {
    cs.mu.Lock()
    defer cs.mu.Unlock()

    if _, ok := cs.data[key1]; !ok {
        cs.data[key1] = make(map[string]*SomeStruct)
    }
    cs.data[key1][key2] = &val
}

func (cs *ConcurrentStruct) Get(key1, key2 string) (val *SomeStruct, ok bool) {
    cs.mu.RLock()
    defer cs.mu.RUnlock()

    if _, ok := cs.data[key1]; ok {
        val, ok := cs.data[key1][key2]
        return val, ok
    }

    return nil, false
}

func main() {
    cs := New()
    cs.Set("a", "b", SomeStruct{"Hello, World!"})

    if _, ok := cs.Get("a", "c"); !ok {
        fmt.Printf("key1=a, key2=c, not found\n")
    }

    if s, ok := cs.Get("a", "b"); ok {
        fmt.Printf("key1=a, key2=b, found: %v\n", s)
    }
}
```